Is the reaction product favoured in this equilibrium: H2(g)+I2(s)><2HI(g) when K=45?
Is the reaction product favoured in this equilibrium: H2(g)+I2(s)><2HI(g) when K=45?
or is the reaction reactant favoured? because I remember that if K>1 then the product is favoured. I am just making sure that my answer is correct.
Thank you!

Yes, you're right that the products are favored. $$K_{c}=\frac{ [A]^{a}*[B]^{b}*[C]^{c}...}{[D]^{d}*[E]^{e}*[F]^{f}...}$$ where [A], [B], [C],... are the activities (essentially concentrations) of the products; a, b, c,... are the stoichiometric coefficients of the products; [D], [E], [F],... are the activities of the reactants; and d, e, f,... are the stoichiometric coefficients of the reagents. So K>1 essentially means that there is "more" of the products at equilibrium, so the products are favored.
